# Changing values while sorting visualization

Tags: reactjs, jsx, visualizer

EDIT:-

the numbers have come up,but for some reason the bars have flipped downwards. One last thing, how can i change the values in the bars while sorting?

Hello i am a newbie in React, and have been recently trying to implement the sorting visualizer using React with clement's tutorial.

```
render() {
    const {array} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="array-container">
        {array.map((value, idx) => (
          <div
            className="array-bar"
            key={idx}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
              height: `${value}px`,
            }}></div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={() => this.resetArray()}>Generate New Array</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.mergeSort()}>Merge Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.quickSort()}>Quick Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.heapSort()}>Heap Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.bubbleSort()}>Bubble Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.testSortingAlgorithms()}>
          Test Sorting Algorithms (BROKEN)
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the "blocks/bars" part of the code, the entire code can be found here : https://github.com/clementmihailescu/Sorting-Visualizer-Tutorial/tree/master/src/SortingVisualizer

So i have been trying to add the value of the element on the block.

I have tried innerHTML , but it was showing random errors

Help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I think this should do the trick - add `{value}` inside your `array-bar` div:

```
{array.map((value, idx) => (
          <div
            className="array-bar"
            key={idx}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
              height: `${value}px`,
            }}>{value}</div>
        ))}
```

Comment: Thanks the numbers have come up,but for some reason the bars have flipped downwards.

One last thing, how can i change the values in the bars while sorting?